# Unable to intercept the code of my remote control at 433 MHz with raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, radio-transmission

I'm trying to reproduce the `code` generated by my universal 4-channel `radio control` with `RaspberryPI`.

1. I cloned my remote with a universal remote like this:
2. I used the libraries included in `433Utils` to test my transmitter and receiver components and `work properly.

I'm using:

```
Transmitter: MX-FS-03V (3.5 - 12V DC)
Receiver: MX-05V (5V DC)
Transmission power: 10mW / Frequency: 433MHz
```

But when I try to read the code registered in my remote control using the `RFSniffer` library, I don't receive any data.
Instead I tried using [rpi-rf](https://github.com/milaq/rpi-rf), if I send a code using the [443Utils](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils) `send` tool, I can read it (with noise).

If I use it with my remote control I can't find any code that makes sense for me:

```
    //the result of a long-pressed key

    2019-12-19 23:17:34 - [INFO] receive: Listening for codes on GPIO 27
    2019-12-19 23:17:39 - [INFO] receive: 992 [pulselength 454, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 375, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 379, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 376, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 379, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 1180, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 514 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 1540 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 1990 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 2082 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 530, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 1152 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 130 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 2 [pulselength 378, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 1323, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 32 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:46 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 1187, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:46 - [INFO] receive: 1088 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:46 - [INFO] receive: 221 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:46 - [INFO] receive: 4096 [pulselength 2069, protocol 4]
    2019-12-19 23:17:46 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:46 - [INFO] receive: 1 [pulselength 1214, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:47 - [INFO] receive: 2 [pulselength 389, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:47 - [INFO] receive: 546 [pulselength 383, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:47 - [INFO] receive: 1280 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:47 - [INFO] receive: 8 [pulselength 391, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:47 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:47 - [INFO] receive: 1024 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 384 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 2048 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 32 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 1152 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 383, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 642 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:48 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 383, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 1 [pulselength 1977, protocol 4]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 576 [pulselength 168, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 2 [pulselength 1197, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 226 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 804 [pulselength 378, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 397, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 437, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 2 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:49 - [INFO] receive: 2084 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 393, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 1284 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 258 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 1092 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 8 [pulselength 848, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:50 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 378, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 1058 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 770 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 768 [pulselength 392, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 584 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 2 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:51 - [INFO] receive: 5 [pulselength 167, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 389, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 8 [pulselength 852, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 1284 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 546 [pulselength 402, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 576 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 34 [pulselength 378, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:52 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 968, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:53 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 383, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:53 - [INFO] receive: 770 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 8 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 186, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 32 [pulselength 403, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 192 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 167, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 66 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 855, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:54 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 383, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 1191, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 1024 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 1998, protocol 4]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 16 [pulselength 932, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 1024 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 1536 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 1280 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:55 - [INFO] receive: 1568 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:56 - [INFO] receive: 32 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:56 - [INFO] receive: 832 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:57 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:57 - [INFO] receive: 1024 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:57 - [INFO] receive: 32 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:57 - [INFO] receive: 1540 [pulselength 383, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:57 - [INFO] receive: 34 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 10 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 770 [pulselength 385, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 415, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 1024 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 832 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 1024 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 1056 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 46 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:58 - [INFO] receive: 32 [pulselength 857, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 856, protocol 5]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 170, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 10 [pulselength 387, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 386, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:59 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 166, protocol 3]
```

My only idea is that the `RFSniffer` library is NOT able to identify the communication protocol of my remote control.

How can I find the code?